# Mixing character sets and collations

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I am setting up a new MySQL database, and going through the default settings that has been provided to me, I was surprised to find that it uses a mix of character sets/collations.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character_set%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';
```

produces:

```
________________________________________________
|                          |                   |
| character_set_client     | latin1            |
| character_set_connection | latin1            |
| character_set_database   | utf8              |
| character_set_server     | latin1            |
| character_set_system     | utf8              |
| collation_connection     | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci |
|______________________________________________|
```

Is it risky to have a combination of latin1 and utf8 in these settings? I have always felt that potential problems will be avoided by using the same (preferably UTF-8/Unicode) everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get into trouble mixing character sets, and it's a big pain to clean it up. The risk is that you'll declare a table with latin1 encoding, and some app will try to store utf8 codes in it. The result is a mess.

Read http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/16/utf8-data-on-latin1-tables-converting-to-utf8-without-downtime-or-double-encoding/ for the proper way to get your data back under control if this happens. If it sounds kind of complicated and risky to you, then you understand it!  :-/

But it's far better to avoid the mess in the first place. Just use `utf8` everywhere from day one. If you need to support the full range of asian languages, then use `utf8mb4`.

Exception: if you have strings that you know will never need to store international symbols, for example a string of hexadecimal digits, then you can declare the character set `ascii` for individual columns in a MySQL table.

But use utf8 as the default at the database and table level, and also for the MySQL connection and on up into the application, Apache, HTTP, etc.

Comment: Commenting @Bill Karwin,
If you don't need character set interpretation just use VARBINARY.
Especially to store hexadecimal digits, VARBINARY stores 50% less than ASCII and no confusion of upper/lower case.

Comment: @elousf, that's not correct. Storing a string of ASCII characters for digits 0-9A-F takes exactly the same space in VARBINARY as it does in any other string data type. If you convert your hex digits to binary values using [UNHEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex), then yes they do take less space. But merely storing a string of hex digits in VARBINARY does not implicitly convert to binary values. It stores the characters as is.